# Converting `AMPL` or `GAMS` files to `Python`

Tags: python, converters, type-conversion, ampl, gams-math

I would like to make some experiments in `Python` with constraint satisfaction problems from [this database](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~neum/glopt/coconut/Benchmark/Library3_new_v1.html): all of the examples there are given in both the `AMPL` and `GAMS` file format. Is there a tool to convert these equations to simple python functions that looks like

> def quadratic(X):

```
 return (X[0]**2 - X[1]**2, 2*X[0]*X[1])
```

and similar?

I have started reading [this manual](http://www.gams.com/dd/docs/api/python/_p_y__o_v_e_r_v_i_e_w.html) but am not sure if that's the right direction. (I'm not very strong at programming.) I will be grateful for possible hints.

Answer (score 4):

I've recently written a parser for a subset of AMPL in Python which is available [here](https://github.com/ampl/global-optimization/blob/master/util/ampl.py). It is incomplete but can already handle many AMPL expressions and can be easily extended.

Here's an example of converting an objective function from AMPL into Python:

```
import ampl, sys

class AMPLToPythonConverter:
  def __init__(self, stream):
    self.stream = stream

  def visit_reference(self, expr):
    self.stream.write(expr.name)

  def visit_binary(self, expr):
    expr.lhs.accept(self)
    self.stream.write(' {} '.format(expr.op))
    expr.rhs.accept(self)

  def visit_decl(self, decl):
    if decl.kind == 'minimize':
      self.stream.write("def {}(x):\n".format(decl.name))
      self.stream.write("  return ");
      decl.body.accept(self)
      self.stream.write('\n')

compound_stmt = ampl.parse(
  """
  var x;
  minimize f: x * x;
  """, "input")

for node in compound_stmt.nodes:
  node.accept(AMPLToPythonConverter(sys.stdout))
```

Running this code prints:

```
def f(x):
  return x * x
```

To keep things simple the example hardcodes argument name `x`, but it is possible to derive it from the AST.

Answer (score 1):

The following connection between GAMS and Pyomo might be of use:

[Pyomo](http://www.pyomo.org/) is a Python-based open-source software package that supports a diverse set of optimization capabilities for formulating, solving, and analyzing optimization models.

The [convert function](https://www.gams.com/latest/docs/S_CONVERT.html) provided by GAMS allows you to generate a Pyomo Concrete scalar model from a GAMS-model.

Hence, you should be able to convert the GAMS model to a Pyomo model and then access its functions via the capabilities provided by Pyomo.

Comment: [convert function](https://www.gams.com/latest/docs/S_CONVERT.html) says "CONVERT comes free of charge with any *licensed* GAMS". Would you know of an opensource GAMS parser / reader that can handle the models in http://www.gamsworld.org/performance/princetonlib/princetonlib.htm ? Thanks

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. Unfortunately, I do not know an opensource parser.